# Teeth popping out of gums when mouth mesh parented to armature

Tags: rigging, armature, parent, pose-mode

I’m having a weird problem where a single mesh made of several manifolds (ie, gums and teeth) is having the teeth transform differently after I parent it to my armature and enter pose mode.

The first picture shows my mesh not parented to anything. All the modifiers have been applied and rotate and scale have been applied too.  After binding it to my armature, the teeth move out of the gums like in the second picture.  I don't see how this is possible since it's all a single mesh.

Any idea what’s going on or how to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your blend. For now I might ask whether you've put the goat in the default pose before parenting it to the armature. Parenting while it's already posed might result in problems like this

Comment: Nevermind.  This turned out to be a weight painting issue.  For some reason the individual teeth were automatically weighted differently from the gums.